# Python.exe crashes without error on pandas.from_json

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following code returns a proper `DataFrame` object in python 3.6.4:

```
from pandas import read_json
bad_data= '{"columns":["Week of: 2018 12 7"],
    "index":["Gizlilik bildirgesini okudum, ankete kat\u0131lmay\u0131 kabul ediyorum","Gizlilik bildirgesini okudum\/okumad\u0131m ankete kat\u0131lmay\u0131 kabul etmiyorum"],
    "data":[[0],[0]]}'
read_json(bad_data, orient='split')
```

[image]

However, in python 3.7.0, a fatal error occurs, **Python has stopped working**:

[image]

Any thoughts on what's causing this failure (and of course, how to fix it)? A few observations:

- If I rename the first row as "Category 1", no error in 3.7.
- If I rename the second row as "Category 2", the error occurs, so this
  *seems* to be somehow related to the contents of the first `index` value.
- However, if I merely remove the first few words from the first index, but leave all the unicode in place, there's no error! (e.g., `bad_data= '{"columns":["Week of: 2018 12 7"], "index":["ankete kat\u0131lmay\u0131 kabul ediyorum","Gizlilik bildirgesini okudum\/okumad\u0131m ankete kat\u0131lmay\u0131 kabul etmiyorum"],"data":[[0],[0]]}'`)

Comment: How big is the JSON data?

Comment: @CharlesLandau you're looking at it. The code exactly as written in the question will reliably produce the error for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it could be related to a segfault in 3.7.0: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22817

Can you try updating to 3.7.1 and see if it still occurs?

Comment: Oooh that looks promising. Will try that and see what happens. Would rather upgrade our server environment to 3.7.1 than rewind it to 3.6.4.